# Selecting columns in a pandas pivot table based on specific row value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in a pivot table dataframe.  The columns are dates labeled 'UniqueDate' and the index is 'Time' of day.  I would like to select all columns where the 10th minute of the day is a positive value. Having some difficulty doing this due to the pivoted nature of the data.

```
UniqueDate  Apr 03, 2015  Apr 04, 2014  Apr 11, 2014  Apr 24, 2015
Time                                                              
00:00:00             NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
00:01:00        0.060665     -0.066291      0.136705      0.000000
00:02:00        0.121326     -0.066291      0.136705      0.000000
00:03:00        0.181984     -0.066291      0.136705      0.059305
00:04:00        0.181984     -0.066291      0.205049      0.000004
00:05:00        0.181984     -0.066291      0.136710      0.059308
00:06:00        0.121330     -0.066291      0.136710      0.059308
00:07:00       -0.060643      0.000004      0.068367      0.000007
00:08:00       -0.242649      0.066295      0.136715      0.118617
00:09:00       -0.242649      0.066295      0.136715      0.059319
00:10:00       -0.181969      0.132582      0.136715      0.059319
```

So in this example id like to return a new dataframe with columns: Apr 04, 2014  Apr 11, 2014  Apr 24, 2015

```
UniqueDate  Apr 04, 2014  Apr 11, 2014  Apr 24, 2015
Time                                                
00:00:00             NaN           NaN           NaN
00:01:00       -0.066291      0.136705      0.000000
00:02:00       -0.066291      0.136705      0.000000
00:03:00       -0.066291      0.136705      0.059305
00:04:00       -0.066291      0.205049      0.000004
00:05:00       -0.066291      0.136710      0.059308
00:06:00       -0.066291      0.136710      0.059308
00:07:00        0.000004      0.068367      0.000007
00:08:00        0.066295      0.136715      0.118617
00:09:00        0.066295      0.136715      0.059319
00:10:00        0.132582      0.136715      0.059319
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df.loc[:,df.columns[df.iloc[10] > 0]]
```

Output:

```
UniqueDate  Apr 04, 2014  Apr 11,  2014  Apr 24, 2014
Time                                                 
00:00:00             NaN            NaN           NaN
00:01:00       -0.066291       0.136705      0.000000
00:02:00       -0.066291       0.136705      0.000000
00:03:00       -0.066291       0.136705      0.059305
00:04:00       -0.066291       0.205049      0.000004
00:05:00       -0.066291       0.136710      0.059308
00:06:00       -0.066291       0.136710      0.059308
00:07:00        0.000004       0.068367      0.000007
00:08:00        0.066295       0.136715      0.118617
00:09:00        0.066295       0.136715      0.059319
00:10:00        0.132582       0.136715      0.059319
```

Comment: Ugh 20 seconds before me