# Select specific rows from pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe which I pivoted and I now want to select spefici rows from the data. I have seen similar questions such as the one here: [Selecting columns in a pandas pivot table based on specific row value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939052/selecting-columns-in-a-pandas-pivot-table-based-on-specific-row-value). In my case I want to return all the columns but I want to select only specific rows.

```
timestamp,value
2008-03-01 00:00:00,55.0
2008-03-01 00:15:00,20.0
2008-03-01 00:30:00,13.0
2008-03-01 00:45:00,78.0
2008-03-01 01:00:00,34.0
2008-03-01 01:15:00,123.0
2008-03-01 01:30:00,25.0
2008-03-01 01:45:00,91.0
2008-03-02 00:00:00,55.0
2008-03-02 00:15:00,46.0
2008-03-02 00:30:00,66.0
2008-03-02 00:45:00,24.0
2008-03-02 01:00:00,70.0
2008-03-02 01:15:00,32.0
2008-03-02 01:30:00,15.0
2008-03-02 01:45:00,92.0
```

I have done the below to generate the below output

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)


df = df.set_index('timestamp')

df['date'] = df.index.map(lambda t: t.date())
df['time'] = df.index.map(lambda t: t.time())
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index='timestamp', columns='time')
df_pivot = df_pivot.fillna(0.0)
print(df_pivot)
```

**Generated output**

```
time                 00:00:00  00:15:00  00:30:00  00:45:00  01:00:00  01:15:00  01:30:00  01:45:00
timestamp                                                                                          
2008-03-01 00:00:00      55.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-01 00:15:00       0.0      20.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-01 00:30:00       0.0       0.0      13.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-01 00:45:00       0.0       0.0       0.0      78.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-01 01:00:00       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0      34.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-01 01:15:00       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0     123.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-01 01:30:00       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0      25.0       0.0
2008-03-01 01:45:00       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0      91.0
2008-03-02 00:00:00      55.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-02 00:15:00       0.0      46.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-02 00:30:00       0.0       0.0      66.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-02 00:45:00       0.0       0.0       0.0      24.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-02 01:00:00       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0      70.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-02 01:15:00       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0      32.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-02 01:30:00       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0      15.0       0.0
2008-03-02 01:45:00       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0      92.0
```

I want to select e.g.,  only the data for `2008-03-01 00:00:00`, `2008-03-01 01:15:00`, and `2008-03-02 01:00:00`.

**Expected output**

```
time                 00:00:00  00:15:00  00:30:00  00:45:00  01:00:00  01:15:00  01:30:00  01:45:00
timestamp                                                                                          
2008-03-01 00:00:00      55.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-01 01:15:00       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0     123.0       0.0       0.0
2008-03-02 01:00:00       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0      70.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
```

How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list of datetimes converted by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
#create DatetimeIndex
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', index_col='timestamp', parse_dates=['timestamp'])
    
#used pandas methods
df['date'] = df.index.date
df['time'] = df.index.time
#added fill_value parameter
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df,values='value',index='timestamp',columns='time',fill_value=0)


L = ['2008-03-01 00:00:00','2008-03-01 01:15:00','2008-03-02 01:00:00']
df = df_pivot.loc[pd.to_datetime(L)]
print (df)
time                 00:00:00  00:15:00  00:30:00  00:45:00  01:00:00  \
2008-03-01 00:00:00        55         0         0         0         0   
2008-03-01 01:15:00         0         0         0         0         0   
2008-03-02 01:00:00         0         0         0         0        70   

time                 01:15:00  01:30:00  01:45:00  
2008-03-01 00:00:00         0         0         0  
2008-03-01 01:15:00       123         0         0  
2008-03-02 01:00:00         0         0         0
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks.